# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::option();

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

```
 **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::option() in
 C:\xampp\htdocs\newtest\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\theme_support_meson\includes\helpers\taxonomies.php:19
 Stack trace: #0
 C:\xampp\htdocs\newtest\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\theme_support_meson\includes\loader.php(55):
 Bunch_Taxonomies->__construct() #1
 C:\xampp\htdocs\newtest\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\theme_support_meson\includes\loader.php(77):
 _load_plugins_class('taxonomies', 'helpers', false) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\newtest\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(286):
 _bunch_plugin_init('') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\newtest\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310):
 WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #4
 C:\xampp\htdocs\newtest\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php(465):
 WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #5
 C:\xampp\htdocs\newtest\wordpress\wp-settings.php(505):
 do_action('init') #6
 C:\xampp\htdocs\newtest\wordpress\wp-config.php(90):
 require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #7
 C:\xampp\htdocs\newtest\wordpress\wp-load.php(37):
 require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs.. in
 C:\xampp\htdocs\newtest\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\theme_support_meson\includes\helpers\taxonomies.php
 on line 19**
```

This Error occurs when I am including new theme in my WordPress account. That time I am using meson theme and try to include new theme and suddenly this error occurs. so guide me on what to do for solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deactivate all plugins associated with the last theme, I can see that the error caused by **theme_support_meson** plugin so make sure to deactivate it then delete it.

Comment: I am not able to log in in my account. And I already try that delete the plugin file from direct folder

Comment: Try to Delete the new theme you have added... see if you can log in now... Waiting for your answer